# Azure Stream Analytics no output header in CSV required

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

We have an ASA job which outputs data every hour to a CSV blob file. However, it also writes a header row which we do not require.

How do I configure ASA job so that the header row is not generated in the output CSV blob file?

Answer (score 0):

From official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs), we could find that there is no option for user to configure the output as CSV format without column header row when using Azure Stream Analytics. Is there any special requirement for you to removing the header row in your CSV file? Whether you could change your output format to JSON or Avro? You could provide your detailed requirement, then we could better help you.

Comment: I had same issue, we want to utilize blob data into poly-base to configure our data warehouse. Is there any other option using we can do the same? I don't preferred manual file generation (using EHP) due to data latency.